# Get Profile Path and Home Folder from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using C# and I'm able to read a lot of values from Active Directory, however I can't figure out how to read the Profile Path, or the Remote Desktop Services Home Folder which are both found on the Remote Desktop Services Profile tab when looking at a user in Active Directory.

Comment: What Server OS? The Profile Path should just be the "profilePath" properties. I'm guessing the other one was supposed to be **Remote** Desktop Services Home Folder, look for TerminalServicesHomeDrive ,TerminalServicesHomeDirectory & TerminalServicesProfilePath in Server 2003 and msTSHomeDrive , msTSHomeDirectory , & msTSProfilePath in Server 2008

Comment: I'm using Windows Server 2008.  You are correct the 2nd value was supposed to be the Remote Desktop Services Home Folder, I've updated my post to fix the typo.

Comment: I've checked all the values you suggested, and all of them are null

Comment: Try using this code in the debugger, it's no where near perfect but will help you see what properties you have on that entry. Dictionary<string, string> dictonaryOfValues = directoryEntry
                            .Properties
                            .OfType<PropertyValueCollection>()
                            .ToDictionary(p => p.PropertyName, p => (p.Value ?? "").ToString());

Comment: I took your suggestion and used that code to see all the properties.  The values you suggested are not listed, nor anything like them.  Is it possible the values I want are in the "UserParameters" property?  That's the only property that I can't read, it's encoded some how and I don't know how to decode it.

Comment: We have ~450 accounts here and only a few admin account have the UserParameters. On mine, almost all the accounts have a profilePath, a homeDirectory, and homeDrive. If you call the directoryEntry.InvokeGet(propertyName) it will return the value or null if the property at least can exist in your environment, otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: There is a newer API/library System.DirectoryService.AccountManagement that is significantly faster, gives you all the properties as objects (instead of in a collection), and seems to pull up old deprecated accounts that the other one wouldn't, it's maxing out at 1000 users for me right now. We have a little over 2000 total accounts, but only ~450 active user so I can get by with a filter. The UserPrincipal object has the HomeDirectory and HomeDrive, still can't find any of the others listed in question worst case you can pull the DirectoryEntry, principal.GetUnderlyingObject() for profilePath

Answer (score 1):

These values store in UserParameters attribute and to get them you can to use InvokeGet here, for example to get Remote Service Profile path:

```
// Get Directory Entry for the object
DirectoryEntry de = New DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, logonName, password);
object prPAth = de.InvokeGet("TerminalServicesProfilePath"); // Remote Desktop Services profile path. If value is empty you'll get an exception here
object homeFolder = de.InvokeGet("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory"); // Remote Desktop Services home folder
```